# Android Facebook SSO Integration Issue

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin.android, monogame

I was developing a game for Android using Xamarin's Mono + MonoGame. On any level, the game includes an option to request help from friends through Facebook. I generated a debug and release hash keys and added both to Facebook. I tested the app on my android 2.3 device in both debug and signed release configurations and Facebook worked fine on both, so I released the app to [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramsayamarin.picwords&hl=en). However, I have 3 friends who have a 4.1.2 & 4.0.4 devices and they told me that Facebook sharing is not working with their devices. On my 2.3 device, clicking the Facebook button would either request a Login or immediately show the share dialog. On a 4.1.2, clicking the Facebook button showed a different screen similar to the one in the image below[image: sample]. Clicking 'ok' simply returned the app to the game with no further actions. If the Facebook button is clicked again at this point, the app just crashes with a java exception. I have ensured that my app's hash keys match the Facebook ones using the [following technique](http://rahulupadhyay.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/facebook-sso/). I doubt the problem is something related to hash keys since the problem occurs only in select devices, and **I was able to solve the problem by disabling SSO, but I would rather solve it without disabling SSO**. So at this point I have no idea why this is happening and I would appreciate any help.